# pgfplots won't plot simple trig function

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot the following function

[image: d=6371000 * arccos(6371000/(6371000+x))]

where arccos(...) outputs a result given in radians

Here is what I've got:

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,a4]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{trig format plots=rad, compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{sansmath}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=0, ymax=6000, xlabel=$h\ \mathrm{(m)}$, ylabel=$d\ \mathrm{(m)}$,]
\addplot[domain = 0:2, range = 0:6000, samples=500, smooth,] {(6371000) * (acos((6371000)/(6371000 + x)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{sansmath}
\end{document}
```

I get an empty plot like this

[image]

As you can see I specify that the functions are in radians at the beginning, and according to Desmos it should be graphed properly from y=0-6000 and x=0-2. I also tried assuming arccos was given in degrees, and it still didn't plot anything. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: The original code also compiles fine with LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX, because LuaLaTeX uses a more precise math engine.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolved** using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=2, ymin=0, ymax=6000, xlabel=$h\ \mathrm{(m)}$, ylabel=$d\ \mathrm{(m)}$,]
\addplot[domain=0:2, smooth] gnuplot[samples=1000] {6371000*acos(6371000/(6371000 + x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I removed some unnecessary parentheses (around acos for example) and used gnuplot. I believe a combination of this caused it to work now, not sure why though...

Comment: Fine. Can you comment in your answer (=solution) what's the significant change? On a quick glance may not be  not obvious.